# how to extract Substring after certain words

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column with following values:

```
Row1: "Storage system. Drive Model: BCD1000EFG disk has failed at port 1."
Row2: "Server model Blade. Disk Drive Model: NDH450TSH HDD has failed at bay 2 enclosure 1."
```

I want to extract value after Drive Model:

```
BCD1000EFG
NDH450TSH
```

Using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, this may be what you need..

> **Make this query as your store_procedure and call it when needed.**

Try modifying it accordingly..

```
DECLARE @LOOP_1 INT=1,@NAME NVARCHAR (MAX),@LEFT NVARCHAR(MAX),@loop_2 int=0
SET @NAME='Server model Blade. Disk Drive Model: NDH450TSH HDD has failed at bay 2 enclosure 1.'

-- First loop started to find where 'Drive Model: ' is located
WHILE @LOOP_1!=(SELECT LEN(@NAME))
BEGIN

SET @LEFT=(LEFT(@NAME,@LOOP_1))
IF @LEFT LIKE '%Drive Model: ' BEGIN
set @NAME=(right(@NAME,len(@name)-@LOOP_1))

-- Second loop started to find where ' ' is located after 'Drive Model: '
WHILE @loop_2!=(SELECT LEN(@NAME))
BEGIN

SET @LEFT=(LEFT(@NAME,@loop_2))
IF @LEFT LIKE '% ' BEGIN
SELECT left(@name,@loop_2-1)
set @loop_2=(SELECT LEN(@NAME)-1)
END
SET @loop_2=@loop_2+1
END

END
SET @LOOP_1=@LOOP_1+1

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Such string manipulations are not fun in SQL Server, because the built-in string processing is not very powerful.  One method is to convert the whole thing to XML, and use the XML processing primitives.

Here is a way you can do it with string munging:

```
select t.*, val2.drive_model
from t outer apply
     (values (stuff(col, 1, charindex('Drive Model: ', col) + 13, ''))
     ) val1(col1_1) outer apply
     (values (left(col1_1, charindex(' '))
     ) val2(drive_model);
```

If your drive model is not in the string, you will need additional logic just to validate the string before doing the operations.  That would look like:

```
from t outer apply
     (values (case when col like '%Drive Model: %'
                   then stuff(col, 1, charindex('Drive Model: ', col) + 13, ''))
              end)
     ) val1(col1_1) . . .
```

Comment: hi Gordon, please can you recheck my row values again. I removed <b> because it suppose NOT to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a parser.  I'm assuming the key is **Model:**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeField varchar(max))
Insert into @YourTable values
('Storage system. Drive Model: BCD1000EFG disk has failed at port 1.'),
('Server model Blade. Disk Drive Model: NDH450TSH HDD has failed at bay 2 enclosure 1.')

    Select A.*
          ,B.Model
     From @YourTable A
     Cross Apply (Select Model=Substring(RetVal,1,CharIndex(' ',RetVal)) From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.SomeField,'Model:') Where RetSeq=2 ) B
```

Returns

```
SomeField                                               Model
Storage system. Drive Model: BCD1000EFG disk...         BCD1000EFG
Server model Blade. Disk Drive Model: NDH450TSH HDD...  NDH450TSH
```

The function if needed.  **I should note**, if you can't use a TVF, the logic can easily be ported into the `Cross Apply`

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@String,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
```

Comment: Modified my answer to single statement within the cross apply